# StringBuilder.insert() not changing output

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a short program that converts any string into T H I S F O N T.

For example: "This is a test sentence" turns into "T H I S I S A T E S T S E N T N C E"

I have a `StringBuilder` inside a `while` loop, but using `finale.insert(i, '\t');` doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Executable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String x;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("Input text here: ");
        x = input.nextLine();

        StringBuilder finale = new StringBuilder(x.toUpperCase());

        while(i > finale.length()) {
            if(finale.substring(i, i) == " ") {
                i += 2;

                finale.insert(i, '\t');
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finale);

    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: while(i > finale.length())  should be while(i < finale.length())

Comment: Also, you are trying to compare Strings using `==`; this is incorrect. Use `string.equals()` instead.

Comment: Plus, your `while` loop will never run because `i` is never greater than the length of your original string.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed what @mettleap said, and made it a .equals, but now it never prints anything. Sorry, I'm still relatively new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code. Before I present an implementation that works, let's look at those other issues.

1. Your `while` loop checks if `i > finale.length()`. Since `i = 0` the `while` loop never has a chance to begin.
2. You are comparing strings using `==` and this is not correct. `==` is used to confirm two **objects** are equal, not the value of two strings.  You would need to use `string.equals()` instead.
3. You're doing too much in your loop anyway. Using a simple `for` loop can accomplish the goal quite simply.

Here is a new loop you can use instead of what you have:

```
for (int i = 1; i < finale.length(); i++) {
    finale.insert(i++, " ");
}
```

The output: `T H I S   F O N T`

---

For those unfamiliar with `for` loops, here's a very simple breakdown of how the above is structured.

The `for` loop is defined in three parts:

```
for (variable_to_increment; repeat_until_this_condition_is_met; modify_variable_on_each_iteration) {
    // Code to be executed during each pass of the loop
}
```

- First, we define a variable that we can track on each loop: `int i = 1`. By setting `i = 1`, we are going to skip the first character in the string.
- The next statement, `i < finale.length()` means that we want to keep repeating this loop until we reach the length of our string. For example, if the string is 5 characters long and we've run the loop 4 times, `i` now equals 5 and is no longer less than the string's length, so the loop ends.
- The last part is `i++`. This tells Java what we want to do with `i` after each loop. In this case, we want to increment the value by 1 each time the loop repeats.
- Everything inside the brackets is, obviously, the code we want to execute on each loop.

Comment: Thank you @Zephyr, this is awesome. I'm still bad with `for` loops, so it can be... difficult. This solves my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I added a little bit of explanation to my answer for how the `for` loop is defined. Hope it helps make it a little easier to understand!

Answer (score 1):

You're saying `while i>finale.length()` but `i` is initialized as 0. You never enter the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues with your code (see inline comments):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Executable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String x;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("Input text here: ");
        x = input.nextLine();

        StringBuilder finale = new StringBuilder(x.toUpperCase());

        while(i > finale.length()) { // this condition is incorrect. Initially
                                     // this condition will always be false
                                     // if you input some sentence. It should be 
                                     // i < finale.length()
            if(finale.substring(i, i) == " ") { // here preferably you should use
                                                // equals method to compare strings
                i += 2;
                // you are only incrementing the i if the ith
                // substring equals " ". Firstly, substring(i,i)
                // will return empty string because the second argument
                // is exclusive
                finale.insert(i, '\t');
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finale);

    }
}
```

If you want to have an alternate method (not very optimal) for doing what you want to do, you can try the following approach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Executable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String x;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("Input text here: ");
        x = input.nextLine();

        String finale = x.toUpperCase().replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("", " ");



        System.out.println(finale);

    }
}
```

First, convert the string to uppercase --> then remove all spaces between the words --> then insert spaces between all letters. The code line which does this is,

```
String finale = x.toUpperCase().replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("", " ");
```

Here is a sample run:

```
Input text here: This is a sentence
 T H I S I S A S E N T E N C E
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct way with your method would be, just increment until you have twice the size of the initial String

   ```
   while (i < x.length() * 2) {
       finale.insert(i, '\t');
       i += 2;
   }
   ```
2. An easier way would be with a classic for-loop:

   ```
   StringBuilder finale = new StringBuilder();
   for (char c : x.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
       finale.append(c).append('\t');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop since you know the number of iterations:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String x;

    System.out.print("Input text here: ");
    x = input.nextLine();

    StringBuilder finale = new StringBuilder(x.toUpperCase());

    int len = finale.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < 2 * len; i+=2 ) {
        finale.insert(i, '\t');
    }

    System.out.println(finale);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings with `==`. Never do that; use `equals` instead.

For future readers: this job can be done elegantly using Java 8 Streams:

```
String result = str.chars()
    .filter(i -> i != ' ')
    .mapToObj(t -> (char) t)
    .map(Character::toUpperCase)
    .map(Character::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ");
```